# 希望 expressing verbs

Tags: usage

This time I have problem with a grammar point.
It's the use of these expressions:

> したい
>
> してほしい、してもらいたい、していただきたい
>
> させたい
>
> させてほしい、させてもらいたい、させていただきたい

My problem comes from the questions the excercise asks me, that are:

誰の希望? and するのはだれ? for each of the verb forms. The anwers, obviously, are 私 and 相手, but don't know in which case the verbs refer to "me" or the "other".

I've recognized that in the last two expressions the verb is in causative form, but this use with -もらう is not so clear to me.

So, I'd like to know when I have to use and how to translate (especially the last two) all these expressions I mentioned above.

Please, help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

したい -> `I want to do something`. Normal form to express what you want to do.

してほしい、してもらいたい、していただきたい -> `I want someone to do something (for me)`. This is used often when you are requesting for help/ favor. The result of the action is usually very important to the requester.

させたい -> `I want (to cause) someone to do something`. This is when you know you have power over someone to do something and it usually focus on that action process (the result of the action usually does not matter).

させてほしい、させてもらいたい、させていただきたい -> `I want someone to cause me to do something` --> `Let me do something (for you)`. This is often used when you are offering help/ service to other people.

**EDIT**

Examples are:

- **したい**: ケーキを食べたい。--> `I want to eat a cake`.
- **してほしい**：明日の打ち合わせのため、A4サイズノートを持ってきてほしい。 --> `For tomorrow's meeting, please bring A4 sized note.`
- **させたい**：弟は病気なので、健康的な食べ物を食べさせたい。 --> `My brother is sick, so I want him to eat healthy food.`
- **させていただきたい**：その件に関して詳しいので、解決させていただきたい。　--> `I am familiar with that matter, so please let me solve it.`

Comment: Ok, thank you. I got your explanation quite well. But, I can't apply it in excercise yet. Could you give me some examples, please?

Comment: For instance, I have to complete this text:
ある母親が自分の息子の教育について話しています。の動詞を適当な形にして文を完成しなさい。使う文型は「-てほしい(してほし) 」、「使役形+たい(させたい)」、「使役形される」です。


将来、子供には医者か外交官に(なる)______ので、大学もできれば医学部か法学部に(行く)_____と思っています。そのために、小学校の時からずっと塾に(通う)_____てきましたし、英語も(習う)_____てきました。もちろんテレビゲムは絶対に(やる)_______し、漫画も(読む)_________。代わりに週に１度水泳を(する)_______、体を鍛え、毎日１時間は小説や詩を(読む)______、教養を(身につける)_________ようにしました。

And it continues like this....but can't understant how to complete the sentences X.X

Comment: it is quite tough question. Not sure if my answer is totally correct: なってほしい (parents want the kid to be)、行かせたい (wish the kid to go)、通わせて (make the kid to go)、習わせて (make the kid to learn)、and I am not sure the rest. I don't think that the parents cause the kid to play TV Game and read manga, so I am not sure what causative form to use here. The last one should be させる, because the parents make the kid do swimming.

Comment: when you use てほしい、 it is usually for the sake of the parents. When it is させる, it is for the sake of the kid.

Comment: You explained much more than I could have wished for! Don't want to bother you anymore, but last question just to search something on the internet: do you know how the last two grammar forms are called?

Comment: Sorry, no. I don't know what it is called in English. Causative? 使役形?. Your textbook should have explained it more in the beginning though.