# Difference between いたします and させていただきます

Tags: grammar, word-choice, politeness

When writing in humble 謙譲語｛けんじょうご} language, I see いたします and させていただきます. What is the difference between these two forms?

For example both mean "I will contact you" in humble language, what is the difference in the two?

> 連絡させていただきます。
>   連絡いたします。

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/54346/9831

Comment: @Chocolate Definitly tangential. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say 連絡させていただきます is "more humble" than 連絡いたします. That said both are acceptable in similar situations.